# for every file in every directory python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, directory, subprocess

I wanted to make a program, that searches for a specific file/extension or checks the file itself.
Im starting in 'C:\\', and I want to appeal the process on every file in subdirectories, so walk over whole pc files. I used os.listdir() before, but it didnt work, will this code work?

```
for path, directories, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
        for file in files:
                try:
                       #finding the file
                except: pass
```

Suggest me more ways please...

Comment: Have you tried it? `os.walk` does indeed walk the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work and it will be more efficient than `os.listdir()` if and only if you want to search everywhere.
If you don't want anything else besides "just searching the file", `os.walk()` is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

all functions return file paths

this will find the first match:

```
import os

def find(name, path="C:\\"):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            return os.path.join(root, name)
```

And this will find all matches:

```
def find_all(name, path="C:\\"):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if name in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
```

And this will match a pattern:

```
import os
import fnmatch

def find(pattern, path="C:\\"):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
```